# Why won't " (800) 555-1212" fit in a varchar(20) field?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server phone number field that is defined as varchar(20). A phone number like '800-555-1212' fits with no issue but a phone number like '(800) 555-1212' will cause a "data will be truncated" error. Why would that be?

Comment: It will fit in a `varchar(20)` column. Any triggers on the table? Have you double checked the table definition? Please show your insert statement.

Comment: Are you using a Unicode encoding like UTF-16?

Comment: How are you inserting the data? What errors/exception are you getting?

Comment: @Oded - How would that work? SQL Server would convert from `nvarchar` to `varchar`

Comment: @MartinSmith - Well, without knowing how the OP is accessing the DB, how do you know that?

Comment: @Oded - What mechanism could they be using that would achieve this result?

Comment: @MartinSmith - I don't know. Which is why I am asking the OP to show what he is doing. That can easily rule out encoding issues.

Comment: Just for confirmation I tried various ways to make this break (including nvarchar/nchar etc.) and could not get the "string or binary data would be truncated" error - always just silent truncation. The only way would be if the column definition was actually smaller than the variable definition (having nothing to do with encoding). So please fill in more details - table structure and an actual insert statement that causes this error.

Answer (score 4):

That example inserts fine into a field defined that way (I ran a test).

You may have some invisible characters adding to the length like tabs and carriage returns.

Or you may have a calculated field (or code in a trigger) that is based on that field  (we have a phone_number_stripped field to store just the numerics) that has accounted for stripping out  - but not ( or ).

Comment: This reminds me of many of Microsoft's forms. They ask for phone number, and you enter it, and they tell you "Invalid phone format!" But they don't give you an example, so you have to guess how your input is failing their validation. Whack-a-mole!

Answer (score 3):

A value could be "like" that value, but be padded with spaces on either end.

Make sure your software handles that case. I recommend allowing the space, but automatically trimming it off.